# How to parse two dict key at same time in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a huge system log file, in which I have a dict that is printing out system data at a particular time,
let's say:

```
{"key1":"val1", "Time":"mon dec 25 12:12:12 2012"}
{"key2":"val2", "key3": "val3", "Time":"mon dec 25 12:12:13 2012"}
```

So basically I am looking for a kind of an and operation between key2 and it's corresponding Time.

I tried the following

```
look = ["key2", "Time"]

for key, val in my_dict.items():
     if key in look:
         print my_dict[key]
```

But this will print out the Time stamp in dict1 as well which is corresponding to key1.

So, how can I look for key2 and it's val2 at it's corresponding time?

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation of what result you're trying to get. Could you show an example of your desired output?

Comment: You have 1 dict or multiple dicts ?

Comment: Sorry for being really bad in explanation. I have multiple dict. but looks like Apero answer is doing the right trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the key is found first, then print the key along with the "Time"

```
for key, val in my_dict.items():
     if key == "key2":
         print my_dict[key]
         print my_dict['Time']
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, because it's no completely clear to me, lat you log is a lit of dicts:

```
log = [
    {"key1":"val1", "Time":"mon dec 25 12:12:12 2012"},
    {"key2":"val2", "key3": "val3", "Time":"mon dec 25 12:12:13 2012"}
]

for d in log:
    if 'key2' in d:
        print d['Time']
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're reading a sequence of dictionaries (from where isn't important) and want to print out certain values from them, but only if the keys for both values are present. In your example, you want the second dictionary's `val2` and time stamp to be printed, but your current code also prints the timestamp from the first dictionary even though it doesn't have a `key2` key.

If so, I think you need to use `all` to test that all the requested keys are present before printing anything.

```
requred_keys = ['key2', 'Time']

for my_dict in sequence_of_dicts:
    if all(key in my_dict for key in required_keys):
        for key in required_keys:
            print my_dict[key]
```